# Minor inconsistency in rendering of tags with counts

Tags: bug, status-completed, rendering, trivial, page-rendering

There's various places where tags are listed in the right sidebar along with counts of how many times the tag is used in posts in the results or in the entire system.

But in two such places they are rendered very slightly differently. I don't know if our SE site designers are perfectionists or how much they care about these details but I thought I'd at least point it out so you know about it so you can decide what to do.

On a [question page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247768/unigrams-bigrams-tf-idf-less-accurate-than-just-unigrams-ff-idf) there will be a section in the sidebar titled "tagged" which has a space on either side of the `×`, I think both are non-breaking spaces:

> [machine-learning](/questions/tagged/machine-learning) **× 1877**

On a [tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) there will be a section in the sidebar titled "**Related Tags**" which only has the space after the `×` but omits the one before:

> [artificial-intelligence](/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence)**× 268**

On a [main page](https://stackoverflow.com/) there will be a section in the sidebar titled "**Recent Tags**" which also only has the space after the `×` but not the one before:

> [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)**× 61**

There may still be other places that list tags in a similar manner, if so I'm not sure which variation they might use.

---

<sup>I found this inconsistency while working on [my site enhancement that adds a Related Tags section for all searches](https://stackapps.com/questions/3686/script-to-add-a-related-tags-module-for-search-on-all-stack-exchange-sites) and wanted to match the native site layout perfectly.</sup>

Comment: I wonder if Jeff has a [giant non-breaking space](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105) available? ;)

Comment: At least it won't break my head when he bludgeons me with it (-;

Answer (score 6):

k, well spotted. We have ordered a new batch of non-breaking spaces - they should be arriving some time just before we next deploy.

Comment: Dammit that means I'll have to add the `&nbsp;` to my extension too d-;

Comment: Sorry to say but I found a third place with such a list and it turns out places had only one `&nbsp;` - so now that you've decided adding an `&nbsp;` was the right fix there's still one that doesn't match: Look for [**Recent Tags** on any main page](http://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: I've dug around the sites and all these pages have a section of numbered tag: `home-page`, `question-page`, `questions-page`, `tagged-questions-page`, `tags-page`, `unanswered-page`. The question page was **the only one** that had a non-breaking space on both sides of the `×` - best solution would be to just change the question page and revert the tag page change. Sorry I wasn't thorough in my initial report, but I wasn't sure anybody would care `\-:`

Comment: @hippietrail the "Recent Tags" on your link looks fine...

Comment: @hippietrail also, there were indeed lots of other utility methods using the "both sides" approach, so the one-sided is not unique/uncommon/correct

Comment: You're right all three now have a space on each side. Well either way I'll leave it all in your court to do as you please now that it's "out there". Love the site either way (-:

Comment: @hippietrail allow me to rephrase: do any now look different?

Comment: Of the three I gave the links for, they all now look alike (space each side). For the others I listen by HTML className but no link I haven't checked.